# Are all sets with finite measure measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In my textbook, it says:

"Let E be any set with m*(E) < $\infty$. Then E is measurable if and only if there exists a measurable set B with m(B) = m*(E)."

There always exists a measurable set of any given measure implying that there always exists a measurable set with measure m*(E). Thus this would imply that all sets with finite measure are measurable. I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly. Is this true? Are all sets with finite measure measurable?

Proof: Let $E$ be measurable. Then take $B = E$. Conversely, let there exist a measurable set $B \supset E$ with $m(B) = m$*$(E)$. Then, by Theroem 3.4.10 (b), we have $m$ * $(E-B) = m$ * $(E) - m$ * $(B) = 0$ Now, $E - B$ being a set of measure zero, is measurable and hence $ E = (E - B) \cup B $ is measurable

Comment: All finite sets are measurable, moreover they all have measure 0.  You can easily cover each point with an arbitrarily small interval

Comment: What textbook is that? Are you sure you quoted it exactly? If so, it is saying that measurability of a set E depends only on the quantity M*(E), which is silly. By the way, are you using "finite set" to mean "set of finite outer measure"? The term "finite set" usually means a set with a finite number of points.

Comment: Perhaps it says "Then E is measurable if and only if there exists a measurable set $B\subseteq E$ with measure m*(E)?

Comment: What is the difference between $m$ and $m^*$?

Comment: @mvw : Probably $m^*$ is _outer_ measure. $\qquad$

Comment: Somewhere it ought to have said $B\subseteq E$; otherwise this doesn't make sense.  However, the answer to what seems to be the main question is yes: all finite sets are measurable. $\qquad$

Comment: Finite sets are measurable, moreover so are countable sets.

Comment: What is your definition for measurablity by the way?

Comment: It's from the textbook "Lebesgue Measure and Integration" by P.K. Jain, V.P. Gupta, Pankaj Jain. Second Edition. pg. 82 Thereom 3.4.11